# My code throws an error that the connection associated with data reader is not closed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Con = New MySqlConnection
    Con.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user = root;  database= employee"

    Try
        Con.Open()
        If TextBox1.Text = "" And TextBox2.Text = "" And TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please fill-up all fields!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New Customer!")
        Else
            Dim theQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE EmpNo=@EmpNo "
            Dim cmd1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(theQuery, Con)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpNo", TextBox1.Text)
            Using reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    ' User already exists
                    MsgBox("User Already Exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Add New User!")
                    reader.Close()
                Else
                    ' User does not exist, add them
                    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Insert into [ordering].[dbo].[accounts] ([EmpNo],[Username],[password]) values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + TextBox3.Text + "')", Con)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    MsgBox("Records Successfully Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Add New Customer!")
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    TextBox2.Text = ""
                    TextBox3.Text = ""
                End If

            End Using
        End If

        Con.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        Con.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You should at least give a full error message and the line causing the error

Comment: When i run the program the it gives 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection must be closed first.'And i don't know where specific close